# How to start a space engineers server?

Tags: hosting, space-engineers

Like any multiplayer game, space engineers also offer server platform for multiple-users to connect. Usually in other games we use to get another application to host a server and the application use to provide us with an ip. Plus we don't seem to have companies offering to host space engineers servers in india.

So my question is simple, how to host a space engineer's server. Is it possible to host on any other hosting companies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a sever up by:

- unzipping the server from located in your steam directory (`DRIVE:Program Files(x86)\Steam\SteamApps\SpaceEngineers\DedicatedServer(64)`)
- run SpaceEngineersDedicated.exe
- configure as needed and provide game a name
- click save config and start
- ensure ports are open on router and firewall
- provide your friends with your [public IP address](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)

  [Server detail space engineers site](http://www.spaceengineersgame.com/dedicated-servers.html)